# AWS MSK Glue Schema Registry fails with 'not authorized to perform: glue:GetSchemaByDefinition'

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

````
Hello,

I'm evaluating MSK for a use case and getting familiar with Glue schema registry integration with IAM AuthN/AuthZ.

I created a producer Lambda function that pushes Avro messages to my topic as such:

```java
KafkaProducer<String, Event> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(Map.of(
                AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapBrokersString,
                AdminClientConfig.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG,
                SecurityProtocol.SASL_SSL.name(),
                SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM,
                "AWS_MSK_IAM",
                SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG,
                IAMLoginModule.class.getName() + " required;",
                SaslConfigs.SASL_CLIENT_CALLBACK_HANDLER_CLASS,
                IAMClientCallbackHandler.class.getName()
                ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class.getName(),
                ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                AWSKafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName(),
                AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.AWS_REGION,
                System.getenv("AWS_REGION"),
                AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.AVRO_RECORD_TYPE,
                AvroRecordType.SPECIFIC_RECORD.name(),
                AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.SCHEMA_AUTO_REGISTRATION_SETTING,
                true,
                AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.COMPATIBILITY_SETTING,
                Compatibility.BACKWARD,
                AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.COMPRESSION_TYPE,
                AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.COMPRESSION.ZLIB.name());
````

But when I attempt to send a message, I get the following error (formatted for brevity):

```
"errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::{accountId}:assumed-role/{roleName} is not authorized to perform: glue:GetSchemaByDefinition on resource: arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:{accountId}:schema/default-registry/events because no identity-based policy allows the glue:GetSchemaByDefinition action (Service: Glue, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 479e6009-3bc8-4088-8657-53a58c85f0bc)",
"errorType": "software.amazon.awssdk.services.glue.model.AccessDeniedException"
```

I've granted the Lambda function the glue:GetSchemaByDefinition action, but as we can see in the error message, it's the STS user that's attempting to perform the action. I'm managing my resources through IaC, and I haven't made any references to STS directly - I'm unsure how to resolve this.

```js
    const producerFunction = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(
      this,
      "ProducerImageFunction",
      {
        // details //
      }
    );

    producerFunction.addToRolePolicy(
      new PolicyStatement({
        effect: Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: [
          "glue:GetSchemaByDefinition",
          "glue:CreateSchema",
          "glue:RegisterSchemaVersion",
          "glue:PutSchemaVersionMetadata",
        ],
        resources: [
          `arn:aws:glue:${region}:${accountId}:registry/*`
        ],
      })
    );
```

Has anyone experienced this?